# XCode Compile: "File Exists" Error; How Do I Fix?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cordova

I had one project which I was compiling and running both in the simulator and in a native device, which I scrapped. I since created a new project with the same name as the one I deleted. But, whenever I go to compile that new app, I get the following error:

```
mkdir: /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.app/www/build/native/My: File exists
```

I have tried:

- Cleaning
- Deleting the ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData folder and all of its contents
- Restarting xCode
- Reinstalling xCode
- Restarting my Mac

None of these does the trick. The app simply will not compile, and I get the error whenever I try to do so?

I wish I could be more specific, but since I don't even know what to look for as indicia of the error, I'll have to await any specific questions, which I can do my best to answer.

What am I doing wrong here?

*UPDATE:* Here is the entire transcript of the build:

```
PhaseScriptExecution "Copy www directory" /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.build/Script-304B58A110DAC018002A0835.sh
    cd /Users/morrissinger/XCodeApplications/UnionConnect
    setenv ACTION build
    setenv ALTERNATE_GROUP staff
    setenv ALTERNATE_MODE u+w,go-w,a+rX
    setenv ALTERNATE_OWNER morrissinger
    setenv ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS NO
    setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_DEVELOPER_DIR /AppleInternal/Developer
    setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_DIR /AppleInternal
    setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_DOCUMENTATION_DIR /AppleInternal/Documentation
    setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_DIR /AppleInternal/Library
    setenv APPLE_INTERNAL_TOOLS /AppleInternal/Developer/Tools
    setenv APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_FILES NO
    setenv ARCHS i386
    setenv ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT i386
    setenv ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS i386
    setenv AVAILABLE_PLATFORMS "iphonesimulator macosx iphoneos"
    setenv BUILD_COMPONENTS "headers build"
    setenv BUILD_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Products
    setenv BUILD_ROOT /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Products
    setenv BUILD_STYLE 
    setenv BUILD_VARIANTS normal
    setenv BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
    setenv CACHE_ROOT /var/folders/zb/9_ts57jj4_b67zhdd8shsqvh0000gn/C/com.apple.Xcode.501
    setenv CCHROOT /var/folders/zb/9_ts57jj4_b67zhdd8shsqvh0000gn/C/com.apple.Xcode.501
    setenv CHMOD /bin/chmod
    setenv CHOWN /usr/sbin/chown
    setenv CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC NO
    setenv CLANG_WARN_CONSTANT_CONVERSION YES
    setenv CLANG_WARN_ENUM_CONVERSION YES
    setenv CLANG_WARN_INT_CONVERSION YES
    setenv CLANG_WARN__DUPLICATE_METHOD_MATCH YES
    setenv CLASS_FILE_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.build/JavaClasses
    setenv CLEAN_PRECOMPS YES
    setenv CLONE_HEADERS NO
    setenv CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.app
    setenv COMMAND_MODE legacy
    setenv COMPOSITE_SDK_DIRS /var/folders/zb/9_ts57jj4_b67zhdd8shsqvh0000gn/C/com.apple.Xcode.501/CompositeSDKs
    setenv COMPRESS_PNG_FILES YES
    setenv CONFIGURATION Debug
    setenv CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
    setenv CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator
    setenv CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH UnionConnect.app
    setenv COPYING_PRESERVES_HFS_DATA NO
    setenv COPY_PHASE_STRIP NO
    setenv COPY_RESOURCES_FROM_STATIC_FRAMEWORKS YES
    setenv CP /bin/cp
    setenv CURRENT_ARCH i386
    setenv CURRENT_VARIANT normal
    setenv DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING NO
    setenv DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS YES
    setenv DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT dwarf-with-dsym
    setenv DEFAULT_COMPILER com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
    setenv DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION NO
    setenv DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING NO
    setenv DERIVED_FILES_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.build/DerivedSources
    setenv DERIVED_FILE_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.build/DerivedSources
    setenv DERIVED_SOURCES_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.build/DerivedSources
    setenv DEVELOPER_APPLICATIONS_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications
    setenv DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
    setenv DEVELOPER_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    setenv DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
    setenv DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR_QUOTED "\"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks\""
    setenv DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library
    setenv DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
    setenv DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
    setenv DEVELOPER_USR_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
    setenv DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE English
    setenv DOCUMENTATION_FOLDER_PATH UnionConnect.app/English.lproj/Documentation
    setenv DO_HEADER_SCANNING_IN_JAM NO
    setenv DSTROOT /tmp/UnionConnect.dst
    setenv DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
    setenv DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME UnionConnect.app.dSYM
    setenv DWARF_DSYM_FILE_SHOULD_ACCOMPANY_PRODUCT NO
    setenv DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
    setenv EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME -iphonesimulator
    setenv ENABLE_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES YES
    setenv EXCLUDED_INSTALLSRC_SUBDIRECTORY_PATTERNS ".DS_Store .svn .git .hg CVS"
    setenv EXCLUDED_RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATH_SUBDIRECTORIES "*.nib *.lproj *.framework *.gch (*) .DS_Store CVS .svn .git .hg *.xcodeproj *.xcode *.pbproj *.pbxproj"
    setenv EXECUTABLES_FOLDER_PATH UnionConnect.app/Executables
    setenv EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH UnionConnect.app
    setenv EXECUTABLE_NAME UnionConnect
    setenv EXECUTABLE_PATH UnionConnect.app/UnionConnect
    setenv FILE_LIST /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.build/Objects/LinkFileList
    setenv FIXED_FILES_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.build/FixedFiles
    setenv FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH UnionConnect.app/Frameworks
    setenv FRAMEWORK_FLAG_PREFIX -framework
    setenv FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS "\"/Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator\" "
    setenv FRAMEWORK_VERSION A
    setenv FULL_PRODUCT_NAME UnionConnect.app
    setenv GCC3_VERSION 3.3
    setenv GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD c99
    setenv GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC NO
    setenv GCC_INLINES_ARE_PRIVATE_EXTERN YES
    setenv GCC_OBJC_LEGACY_DISPATCH YES
    setenv GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL 0
    setenv GCC_PFE_FILE_C_DIALECTS "c objective-c c++ objective-c++"
    setenv GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER YES
    setenv GCC_PREFIX_HEADER UnionConnect/UnionConnect-Prefix.pch
    setenv GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN YES
    setenv GCC_THUMB_SUPPORT NO
    setenv GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS NO
    setenv GCC_VERSION com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
    setenv GCC_VERSION_IDENTIFIER com_apple_compilers_llvm_clang_1_0
    setenv GCC_WARN_ABOUT_RETURN_TYPE YES
    setenv GCC_WARN_UNINITIALIZED_AUTOS YES
    setenv GCC_WARN_UNUSED_VARIABLE YES
    setenv GENERATE_MASTER_OBJECT_FILE NO
    setenv GENERATE_PKGINFO_FILE YES
    setenv GENERATE_PROFILING_CODE NO
    setenv GID 20
    setenv GROUP staff
    setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_FLAT_ENTRIES_FOR_TARGET_BEING_BUILT YES
    setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_FRAMEWORK_ENTRIES_FOR_ALL_PRODUCT_TYPES YES
    setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_NONPUBLIC_NONPRIVATE_HEADERS YES
    setenv HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_PROJECT_HEADERS YES
    setenv HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS "\"/Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include\" \"/Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/usr/local/lib/include\" \"/Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UninstalledProducts/include\" \"/Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator\""
    setenv ICONV /usr/bin/iconv
    setenv INFOPLIST_EXPAND_BUILD_SETTINGS YES
    setenv INFOPLIST_FILE UnionConnect/UnionConnect-Info.plist
    setenv INFOPLIST_OUTPUT_FORMAT binary
    setenv INFOPLIST_PATH UnionConnect.app/Info.plist
    setenv INFOPLIST_PREPROCESS NO
    setenv INFOSTRINGS_PATH UnionConnect.app/English.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
    setenv INSTALL_DIR /tmp/UnionConnect.dst/Applications
    setenv INSTALL_GROUP staff
    setenv INSTALL_MODE_FLAG u+w,go-w,a+rX
    setenv INSTALL_OWNER morrissinger
    setenv INSTALL_PATH /Applications
    setenv INSTALL_ROOT /tmp/UnionConnect.dst
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.0
    setenv JAVAC_DEFAULT_FLAGS "-J-Xms64m -J-XX:NewSize=4M -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"
    setenv JAVA_APP_STUB /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Resources/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
    setenv JAVA_ARCHIVE_CLASSES YES
    setenv JAVA_ARCHIVE_TYPE JAR
    setenv JAVA_COMPILER /usr/bin/javac
    setenv JAVA_FOLDER_PATH UnionConnect.app/Java
    setenv JAVA_FRAMEWORK_RESOURCES_DIRS Resources
    setenv JAVA_JAR_FLAGS cv
    setenv JAVA_SOURCE_SUBDIR .
    setenv JAVA_USE_DEPENDENCIES YES
    setenv JAVA_ZIP_FLAGS -urg
    setenv JIKES_DEFAULT_FLAGS "+E +OLDCSO"
    setenv KEEP_PRIVATE_EXTERNS NO
    setenv LD_GENERATE_MAP_FILE NO
    setenv LD_MAP_FILE_PATH /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.build/UnionConnect-LinkMap-normal-i386.txt
    setenv LD_NO_PIE NO
    setenv LEGACY_DEVELOPER_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer
    setenv LEX lex
    setenv LIBRARY_FLAG_NOSPACE YES
    setenv LIBRARY_FLAG_PREFIX -l
    setenv LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS "\"/Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator\" "
    setenv LINKER_DISPLAYS_MANGLED_NAMES NO
    setenv LINK_FILE_LIST_normal_i386 /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.build/Objects-normal/i386/UnionConnect.LinkFileList
    setenv LINK_WITH_STANDARD_LIBRARIES YES
    setenv LOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH UnionConnect.app/English.lproj
    setenv LOCAL_ADMIN_APPS_DIR /Applications/Utilities
    setenv LOCAL_APPS_DIR /Applications
    setenv LOCAL_DEVELOPER_DIR /Library/Developer
    setenv LOCAL_LIBRARY_DIR /Library
    setenv MACH_O_TYPE mh_execute
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv MAC_OS_X_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION 12C60
    setenv MAC_OS_X_VERSION_ACTUAL 1082
    setenv MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAJOR 1080
    setenv MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MINOR 0802
    setenv NATIVE_ARCH i386
    setenv NATIVE_ARCH_32_BIT i386
    setenv NATIVE_ARCH_64_BIT x86_64
    setenv NATIVE_ARCH_ACTUAL x86_64
    setenv NO_COMMON YES
    setenv OBJC_ABI_VERSION 2
    setenv OBJECT_FILE_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.build/Objects
    setenv OBJECT_FILE_DIR_normal /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.build/Objects-normal
    setenv OBJROOT /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates
    setenv ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH NO
    setenv OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL 0
    setenv OS MACOS
    setenv OSAC /usr/bin/osacompile
    setenv OTHER_LDFLAGS "-weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak-lSystem -all_load -Obj-C"
    setenv PACKAGE_TYPE com.apple.package-type.wrapper.application
    setenv PASCAL_STRINGS YES
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/libexec:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv PATH_PREFIXES_EXCLUDED_FROM_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES "/usr/include /usr/local/include /System/Library/Frameworks /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Headers /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/SDKs /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms"
    setenv PBDEVELOPMENTPLIST_PATH UnionConnect.app/pbdevelopment.plist
    setenv PFE_FILE_C_DIALECTS objective-c
    setenv PKGINFO_FILE_PATH /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.build/PkgInfo
    setenv PKGINFO_PATH UnionConnect.app/PkgInfo
    setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_APPLICATIONS_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications
    setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin
    setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library
    setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
    setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Tools
    setenv PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr
    setenv PLATFORM_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform
    setenv PLATFORM_NAME iphonesimulator
    setenv PLATFORM_PREFERRED_ARCH i386
    setenv PLATFORM_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION 10B141
    setenv PLATFORM_VERSION_AVAILABILITY_H_FORMAT 60100
    setenv PLIST_FILE_OUTPUT_FORMAT binary
    setenv PLUGINS_FOLDER_PATH UnionConnect.app/PlugIns
    setenv PRECOMPS_INCLUDE_HEADERS_FROM_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR YES
    setenv PRECOMP_DESTINATION_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.build/PrefixHeaders
    setenv PRESERVE_DEAD_CODE_INITS_AND_TERMS NO
    setenv PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH UnionConnect.app/PrivateHeaders
    setenv PRODUCT_NAME UnionConnect
    setenv PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH /Users/morrissinger/XCodeApplications/UnionConnect/UnionConnect/UnionConnect-Info.plist
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
    setenv PROFILING_CODE NO
    setenv PROJECT UnionConnect
    setenv PROJECT_DERIVED_FILE_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/DerivedSources
    setenv PROJECT_DIR /Users/morrissinger/XCodeApplications/UnionConnect
    setenv PROJECT_FILE_PATH /Users/morrissinger/XCodeApplications/UnionConnect/UnionConnect.xcodeproj
    setenv PROJECT_NAME UnionConnect
    setenv PROJECT_TEMP_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build
    setenv PROJECT_TEMP_ROOT /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates
    setenv PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH UnionConnect.app/Headers
    setenv RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATHS_FOLLOW_SYMLINKS YES
    setenv REMOVE_CVS_FROM_RESOURCES YES
    setenv REMOVE_GIT_FROM_RESOURCES YES
    setenv REMOVE_HG_FROM_RESOURCES YES
    setenv REMOVE_SVN_FROM_RESOURCES YES
    setenv REZ_COLLECTOR_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.build/ResourceManagerResources
    setenv REZ_OBJECTS_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.build/ResourceManagerResources/Objects
    setenv REZ_SEARCH_PATHS "\"/Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator\" "
    setenv RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER NO
    setenv SCAN_ALL_SOURCE_FILES_FOR_INCLUDES NO
    setenv SCRIPTS_FOLDER_PATH UnionConnect.app/Scripts
    setenv SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_COUNT 0
    setenv SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_COUNT 0
    setenv SDKROOT /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk
    setenv SDK_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk
    setenv SDK_NAME iphonesimulator6.1
    setenv SDK_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION 10B141
    setenv SED /usr/bin/sed
    setenv SEPARATE_STRIP NO
    setenv SEPARATE_SYMBOL_EDIT NO
    setenv SET_DIR_MODE_OWNER_GROUP YES
    setenv SET_FILE_MODE_OWNER_GROUP NO
    setenv SHALLOW_BUNDLE YES
    setenv SHARED_DERIVED_FILE_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DerivedSources
    setenv SHARED_FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH UnionConnect.app/SharedFrameworks
    setenv SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders
    setenv SHARED_SUPPORT_FOLDER_PATH UnionConnect.app/SharedSupport
    setenv SKIP_INSTALL NO
    setenv SOURCE_ROOT /Users/morrissinger/XCodeApplications/UnionConnect
    setenv SRCROOT /Users/morrissinger/XCodeApplications/UnionConnect
    setenv STRINGS_FILE_OUTPUT_ENCODING binary
    setenv STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT YES
    setenv STRIP_STYLE all
    setenv SUPPORTED_DEVICE_FAMILIES "1 2"
    setenv SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS "iphonesimulator iphoneos"
    setenv SYMROOT /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Products
    setenv SYSTEM_ADMIN_APPS_DIR /Applications/Utilities
    setenv SYSTEM_APPS_DIR /Applications
    setenv SYSTEM_CORE_SERVICES_DIR /System/Library/CoreServices
    setenv SYSTEM_DEMOS_DIR /Applications/Extras
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_APPS_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DEMOS_DIR "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Built Examples"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DOC_DIR "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_GRAPHICS_TOOLS_DIR "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Graphics Tools"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_JAVA_TOOLS_DIR "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Java Tools"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_PERFORMANCE_TOOLS_DIR "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Performance Tools"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_RELEASENOTES_DIR "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/releasenotes"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DOC_DIR "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/documentation/DeveloperTools"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_RELEASENOTES_DIR "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/releasenotes/DeveloperTools"
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
    setenv SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_UTILITIES_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities
    setenv SYSTEM_DOCUMENTATION_DIR /Library/Documentation
    setenv SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR /System/Library
    setenv TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY 1,2
    setenv TARGETNAME UnionConnect
    setenv TARGET_BUILD_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
    setenv TARGET_NAME UnionConnect
    setenv TARGET_TEMP_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.build
    setenv TEMP_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.build
    setenv TEMP_FILES_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.build
    setenv TEMP_FILE_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.build
    setenv TEMP_ROOT /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates
    setenv TEST_AFTER_BUILD NO
    setenv TOOLCHAINS com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault
    setenv UID 501
    setenv UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH UnionConnect.app
    setenv UNSTRIPPED_PRODUCT NO
    setenv USER morrissinger
    setenv USER_APPS_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Applications
    setenv USER_LIBRARY_DIR /Users/morrissinger/Library
    setenv USE_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC YES
    setenv USE_HEADERMAP YES
    setenv USE_HEADER_SYMLINKS NO
    setenv VALIDATE_PRODUCT NO
    setenv VALID_ARCHS i386
    setenv VERBOSE_PBXCP NO
    setenv VERSIONPLIST_PATH UnionConnect.app/version.plist
    setenv VERSION_INFO_BUILDER morrissinger
    setenv VERSION_INFO_FILE UnionConnect_vers.c
    setenv VERSION_INFO_STRING "\"@(#)PROGRAM:UnionConnect  PROJECT:UnionConnect-\""
    setenv WRAPPER_EXTENSION app
    setenv WRAPPER_NAME UnionConnect.app
    setenv WRAPPER_SUFFIX .app
    setenv XCODE_APP_SUPPORT_DIR /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode
    setenv XCODE_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION 4H512
    setenv XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL 0461
    setenv XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR 0400
    setenv XCODE_VERSION_MINOR 0460
    setenv YACC yacc
    /bin/sh -c /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Intermediates/UnionConnect.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.build/Script-304B58A110DAC018002A0835.sh

mkdir: /Users/morrissinger/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnionConnect-fxrtfyqfklfejieapsrdftozwzdl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnionConnect.app/www/build/native/My: File exists
```

Comment: Is this the only error that shows up, or are there others?

Comment: This is it. I will add the whole transcript of the build, above.

Comment: I would check to see if you have an explicit scripting phase, because it appears that it's copying some files into the app bundle, which is a huge problem

Comment: There is a www folder which contains an HTML5/JS app, which gets included in the project; this is a PhoneGap app.

Comment: Well, then, this may be of some relevance: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phonegap/82gOLXkB6TE/5YC_JXZD--8J.  Old versions of PhoneGap don't tend to play nicely with Xcode.

Comment: I appreciate that. However, the version of PhoneGap I am using was released less than 40 days ago, and is the newest release.

Comment: Try change Build locations from absolute to relative to Poject in XCode (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-locations_preferences/About/About.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010523-CH1-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the comments which were able to put me enough in the right direction that I could fix this.

Problem was that I had symlinked my www folder (for PhoneGap) from another place on my disk. And, then, when I copied it over instead, I continued to get the error (as well as a dialog box that popped up saying nothing more than "The Argument is Invalid") until I removed the "build" directory from my www directory (it's included with Sencha Touch).

So, the lessons apparently are:

1. Do not symlink the www directory in a PhoneGap app with the most recent version of PhoneGap (2.5.0) because it won't work without some further modifications to the build process, and
2. If you are making a Sencha Touch app in the most recent version of PhoneGap, delete the Build directory before running the app on your device, you you'll get something very similar to the error I described in the original post.